# What languages or libraries will I need in order to write a cross-platform game?

Tags: cross-platform

What languages or libraries will I need in order to write a cross-platform game?
Can I just build one game that will work on all platforms, or must I recompile for each platform?

Comment: Another is there a a cross-platform UI library?

Comment: -1, it is not possible to give a good answer to such a unspecific question without more information. Will remove the downvote when you provide us with more details.

Comment: I am new to programming so just give me a opinion and then i can google :)

Comment: What kind of game? Solitaire card game? Side-scrolling platformer? Single player? Multiplayer? 3D first person shooter? The answers to these questions will, to some extent, help limit your possible choices.

Comment: a 2d or 3d game, maybe multiplayer

Comment: I think you successfully narrowed down those choices to "all of the above". Good luck.

Comment: @Snoob: if you are new to programming, IMHO it would be best to start just with one platform. And more important, make a decision what kind of game - that will be much more important for choosing your programming environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ with a multi-platform library like SDL.

Comment: On each platform? Generally yes, or look into cross-compilation.

Comment: Cross-compilation involves recompiling.

Comment: Thanks, i knew what i need to learn (bad grammar lol)

Answer (score 6):

For a simple  game, Python with [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/about).

For a large-scale or performance-intensive game, C++ is the most popular choice.

Answer (score 3):

Java + JOGL (OpenGL bindings) or Java3D. Quake has been ported to this combination. see http://jogamp.org/

Answer (score 2):

Well, that really depends what kind of game you want to write. You could use C++ and reompile or Java in what you can write 3d accelerated games as well. You could make it a Flash game that runs in the browser and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately an web based game, as all platforms allow browsing internet, if you need somethign more powerfull i would go for Java, and if you really want a powerful lgame (3d engine etc) C++.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript with the new Canvas element is a very mighty tool.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at PuppyGames - they make some very cool arcade games in JavaWebStart.